# Count of values in a pandas df

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to `count` the amount of `values` in a `pandas df`. I want to do this `row` by `row`. So for the `df` below I want to `count` the amount of `values` in each `column` exported `row` by `row`

```
d = ({
    'A' : [[(1,2),(3,4)],[(1,2)],[()],[(1,2)]],     
    'B' : [[(1,2)],[(1,2)],[(1,2),(3,4)],[(1,2)]],
    'C' : [[(1,2)],[()],[()],[()]],            
    'D' : [[()],[(1,2),(3,4)],[(1,2),(3,4)],[()]], 
    })

df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
```

I tried to do this using:

```
l = ([len(i) for i in df])
```

Output

```
[1, 1, 1, 1]
```

Were as I'm hoping the intended output is:

```
   A  B  C  D
0  2  1  0  1
1  1  1  2  1
2  1  0  0  0
3  0  2  2  0
```

Comment: Is output correct? do you need transpose final Dataframe?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [`applymap`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.applymap.html) with `if-else`:

```
df = df.applymap(lambda x: len(x) if x != [()] else 0)
#alternative
#df = df.applymap(lambda x: 0 if x == [()] else len(x))
print (df)
   A  B  C  D
0  2  1  1  0
1  1  1  0  2
2  0  2  0  2
3  1  1  0  0
```

Last if need transpose output:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame(df.T.values, index=df.index, columns=df.columns)
print (df1)
   A  B  C  D
0  2  1  0  1
1  1  1  2  1
2  1  0  0  0
3  0  2  2  0
```